# What does the word "Kraftäußerung" mean?

Tags: meaning

I stumbled upon this word in an old text I'm reading, and I can't seem to find its definition in the dictionaries nor on the internet.

The text is Schopenhauer's, demonstrating his views on women and their role. Here's the sentence where the word is found:

> *"Die heftigsten Leiden, Freuden und Kraftäußerungen sind ihm [dem Weib] nicht beschieden; sondern sein Leben soll stiller, unbedeutsamer und gelinder dahinfließen, als das des Mannes, ohne wesentlich glücklicher, oder unglücklicher zu seyn."*

Comment: More context please. Please quote the complete sentence, and what kind of text it was.

Comment: Compare: »What does the word "*turn*" mean?« Some possible contexts: »*Turn* the knob clockwise« »You have to *turn* right at the corner« »*Turn* to page 20« »Leaves *turn* red in autumn« »The milk tastes awful. It has *turned*« »Midas *turned* everything into gold« »The prisoners *turned* on the warden.«

Comment: There you go, I added a piece of the text

Comment: That context was really necessary, without it I would have guessed that speech using swear words is meant.

Comment: I found your German sentence here: http://aboq.org/schopenhauer/parerga2/weiber.htm Then I searched for "Schopenhauer On Women" and found this english translation: http://www.theabsolute.net/misogyny/onwomen.html

Comment: @CarstenS: After reading the context, I *still* think that is possibly what was meant.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Schopenhauer verwendet sein _»soll«_ nicht in dem Sinne, dass er beschreibt, wie Frauen seiner Meinung nach sein sollen. Vielmehr beschreibt er, wie die Frau von Natur aus gestaltet sei. Wenn wir nun unterstellen, dass mit Kraftäußerungen Schimpfwörter gemeint sind, würde Schopenhauer so viel gesagt haben wie: _»Die Frau ist by Design nicht in der Lage, zu fluchen.«_

Comment: @Pollitzer: Und inwiefern ist das abwegig, wenn im selben Satz Entsprechendes über Freude behauptet wird?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Die Intensität seelischer Glücks- und Schmerzempfindungen steigt nach Schopenhauer mit der Sensibilität des Gehirns. Je höher das Gehirn entwickelt ist, d. h. je näher einer dem Genie kommt, umso greller sind seine Empfindungen. Und je stumpfer das Gehirn, umso flacher die Empfindungen. Im Klartext: Die Frau kann weder himmelhoch jauchzen noch zu Tode betrübt sein, dafür ist sie zu blöd. Mental gesehen ist sie ein Ding zwischen Kind und Mann – nach Schopenhauer. (→ [§ 366](http://aboq.org/schopenhauer/parerga2/weiber.htm))

Answer (score 5):

Schopenhauer assesses the intellectual abilities of women according to their lower physical strength, classifies women in both fields inferior to men.

Wider context of your quotation:

> **Schon der Anblick der weiblichen Gestalt lehrt, daß das Weib weder zu
>   großen geistigen, noch körperlichen Arbeiten bestimmt ist.** Es trägt
>   die Schuld des Lebens nicht durch Thun, sondern durch Leiden ab, durch
>   die Wehen der Geburt, die Sorgfalt für das Kind, die Unterwürfigkeit
>   unter den Mann, dem es eine geduldige und aufheiternde Gefährtin seyn
>   soll. Die heftigsten Leiden, Freuden und **Kraftäußerungen** sind ihm
>   nicht beschieden; sondern sein Leben soll stiller, unbedeutsamer und
>   gelinder dahinfließen, als das des Mannes, ohne wesentlich
>   glücklicher, oder unglücklicher zu seyn.
>
> <sub>Source: [§ 363](http://aboq.org/schopenhauer/parerga2/weiber.htm)</sub>

So by *»Kraftäußerungen«* he means considerable intellectual and physical performance.

Comment: Sehr gute Antwort, denn erst der weitere Kontext macht den Ausdruck verständlich. Vielleicht sollte man noch hinzufügen: Ohne diesen Kontext gerät man leicht in Gefahr, *Kraftäußerung* mit *Kraftausdruck* (= derber, vulgärer Ausdruck von Ärger, Erstaunen o.ä.) zu verwechseln. Interessant: Dudens Deutsches Universalwörterbuch (2. Aufl. 1989, 1816 Seiten) nennt nur *Kraftausdruck", nicht aber *Kraftäußerung*.

Comment: Im letzten Satz, wo kommen die intellektuellen Leistungen her? Wieso nicht nur physische Leistungen?

Comment: @userunknown: Bezieht sich auf den ersten zitierten Satz: _»... dass das Weib weder zu großen geistigen noch körperlichen Arbeiten bestimmt ist.«_

Comment: Leiden und Freuden sind aber keine geistigen oder körperlichen Arbeiten. Ebenso sind nicht alle Kraftäußerungen Arbeit. Der dritte Satz ist also keine Wiederholung des ersten.

Comment: @userunknown: Ich glaube, dass mit Kraftäußerungen das gemeint ist, was der menschliche Körper physisch zu leisten vermag, sei es nun Arbeit oder nicht.

Comment: @Pollitzer: Die europäische Philosophie mit einer weit zurückreichenden Tradition zwischen Geist und Körper zu unterscheiden legt aber nahe, dass Schopenhauer intellektuelle Leistungen nicht als physische verstanden hat bzw. es kenntlich gemacht hätte, hätte er das ausdrücken wollen.

Answer (score 4):

This is a compound substantive formed from

**Kraft** - Power, strength

and

**Äußerung** - expression, exhibition of something.

So it could be translated to "exhibition of strength".

Contemporary translations to English used it like so:

> The greatest sorrows and joys or great exhibition of strength are not assigned to her; her life should flow more quietly, more gently, and less obtrusively than man’s, without her being essentially happier or unhappier.

Comment: Ok, there's just a question I'd like to ask you. Given the translation you've given, it looks as if you did know the text beforehand, am I right?

Comment: Sure. It's probably the piece of most misogynic literature ever written in German, and thus pretty well-known. Schopenhauer was a mad bastard in that respect.

Answer (score 3):

The passage translates: 
"The heftiest sufferings, joys, and *exertions of force* are not given to her [woman], but her life shall be quieter, less significant, and gentler than that of the man, without her being much happier or unhappier."

The author was saying that women were less "hefty" and "forceful" than men, and would therefore live quieter and gentler (but less significant) lives. Their "overall" happiness would be about the same as that of men, but with fewer highs and lows.